# Get proper stacktrace after proguard compression and app deployment

Tags: android, google-analytics, stack-trace, android-proguard

I have deployed my first app and I am catching the exceptions using google analytics. I am recording the stacktrace.

```
[in.jiyofit.basic_app.WorkoutActivity.a(Unknown Source), 
in.jiyofit.basic_app.WorkoutActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(Unknown Source),
```

How to interpret what should be in the "Unknown Source"? I believe this is happening because of proguard. Is there a way I can even get the line numbers during the crash/exception. Follow is the code to find the exception:

```
public void trackException(Exception e) {
    if (e != null) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

        t.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
                .setDescription(
                        new StandardExceptionParser(this, null)
                                .getDescription(Thread.currentThread().getName(), e))
                .setFatal(false)
                .build()
        );

        SharedPreferences loginPrefs = getSharedPreferences("LoginInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
        userID = loginPrefs.getString("userID", "");
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(userID.length() > 0){
            trackEvent("Exception", "userID: " + userID + " Date: " + currentTime + " " + e.getClass().getSimpleName(), Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
            trackEvent("Exception", "userID: " + userID + " Date: " + currentTime + " " + e.getClass().getSimpleName(), "SDK: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + " Manu: " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " Model: " + Build.MODEL);
        } else {
            trackEvent("Exception", "Date: " + currentTime + " " + e.getClass().getSimpleName(), Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
            trackEvent("Exception", "Date: " + currentTime + " " + e.getClass().getSimpleName(), "SDK: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + " Manu: " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " Model: " + Build.MODEL);
        }
    }
}
```

*EDIT:*
I am trying to follow Gopal's answer below. 
I get the stacktrace in this way: `Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace())`
I have recorded the following stacktrace:

```
[in.jiyofit.basic_app.WorkoutActivity.a(Unknown Source), 
in.jiyofit.basic_app.WorkoutActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(Unknown Source), 
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2777), 
android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:7995), 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:968),
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3171), 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102), 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136), 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433), 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method), 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515), 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268), 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084), 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)]
```

But this is not being processed properly to get the deobfuscated code. The deobfuscated code gives the obfuscated code as the output. So,
1. How should the stacktrace be stored for proguardgui to interpret it? `Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace())` doesn't seem to work properly
2. How should I edit the given stacktrace for proguard to interpret and deobfuscate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to sdk directory `\\Androidsdk\tools\proguard\bin` and open `proguardgui.bat`
There is an option to retrace, with this option you can put your mapping file generated by proguard and obfuscated stacktrace and get original stacktrace with proper line numbers.

Comment: I have followed your steps but for some reason my stacktrace is not giving the result. I have edited the question accordingly. Can you please see it and tell me what is the error I am making?

Comment: go to `build/outputs/proguard/release/mapping.txt ` and put this mapping in proguardgui.bat to retrace this stacktrace.

Comment: I did that..But I am still getting the obfuscated stacktrace as the deobfuscated stacktrace